Measurement error R in Kalman Filter
I want to calculate the measurement error R for Kalman filter if I have such data:
True value of the golden bar is 18 g. A tool was used to measure the weight of the bar: 17.7, 17.8, 18.1, 17.8.
How to calculate the measurement error R in the Kalman filter, if I have such data?
If possible please make a link to the literature.
Thank you in advance for any help!
